# Нет соединения с локальным сайтом на одной из машин

Tags: сеть

Есть некая сеть из десятка машин, на одной из них отсутствует соединение с локальным сайтом. Никаких политик блокировок не установлено, адреса розданы корректно, брандмауэр ничего не блокирует. В чем может быть проблема ?

Windows 10

Comment: Сделайте трассировку и посмотрите где обвал. Ну или скрин в студию `tracert google.com` в консоле

Comment: Спасибо, проблема оказалась в Hosts